# In SSIS, executing package for a Target Server 2012 in my computer fails but when i change to 2016 it works

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm importing existing SSIS packages that are targeted for SQL Server 2012.

While executing the SSIS package from VS 2017 with SSDT 15.8.0 (SQL Server 2016) 
I'm getting this error:

> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: The component metadata for "ODBC SOURCE, clsid {XXXXXXXXX}" could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method failed.

Now, I created a new very simple package with an ODBC DATA FLOW and made target version SQL Server 2016 and it works fine.

But when I change the version to 2012, I have the same problem again.

In Other Words, it works for packages version 8 but not version 6!
All the topics i find are about the other way round!

How can I fix that?

Thanks!